# Invalid syntax in a batch file comment

Tags: batch-file

So apparently it's possible to have invalid syntax in batch file comments. Could someone please explain why the code below causes a syntax error when it's in a batch file?

```
rem %~mdir%
```

The exact message cmd.exe spits out says:

```
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~mdir%

For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Comment: @Compo Yes, that's the entire content of the batch file. I ran it using cmd.exe and it says 
"`The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~mdir%

For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
The syntax of the command is incorrect.`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rem` command is recognised after (immediate) variable expansion, which also includes expansion of [argument references](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html), like `%0`, `%1`, `%2`, etc. These arguments also support `~`-modifiers (like `%~1` or `%~f1`, for instance). So the command interpreter detects `%~` and now it expects either a decimal digit or a valid modifier (`d`, `p`, `n`, `x`, `f`, `s`, `a`, `t`, `z`, or `$ENV:`, where `ENV` is a variable), both of which are not present. That is why a fatal syntax error arises, which even aborts execution of the remaining script.

Take also a look at this thread for more details: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699) (pay particular attention to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970912))

Comment: Also rem /? will try to give a help message or error, even if /? is part of a webpage address.

Comment: Yes, @js2010, `rem` is quite greedy for `/?`, but luckily this can be avoided when writing `rem/ /?`…